# How to sum up a column of data that meets a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

How can I do a simple summation of data that meets a certain condition? Say i have the data

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 -7 8
```

for finding the average I can just type in a cell `=AVERAGE(A1:B4)`, but how can I find the average of only the positive numbers into a block of data?

I realize the `IF` statement would probably be used here, but how? Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `AVERAGEIF` function of Excel. The [documentation is provided here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB). If your data was in cells `A1:D2`, the following function would only average the data that was above zero:

`=AVERAGEIF(A1:D2,">0")`

If you want to use multiple criteria, then you can use the `AVERAGEIFS` function, which is similar but allows multiple conditions. The documentation [is provided here](https://support.office.com/en-GB/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-4cca2550-dab3-41c4-bcd2-648e17f20553). The only catch is you have to define the range to average, which in your case could just be the same range. If your data was in cells `A1:D2`, the following function would only average the data that was both above zero and less than or equal to 6:

`=AVERAGEIFS(A1:D2,A1:D2,">0","<=6")`

Answer (score 1):

Try: =AVERAGEIF(A1:B4;">0";A1:B4)

Works in excel 2013.